# Is it OK not to specify class name with @WebListener (unlike @WebServlet)?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-listeners

Do I ever have to specify class name for `@WebListener` annotation like I have to do for `@WebServlet("/MyClassname")` ?

In my application just `@WebListener` works fine, but I have only *single* *ServletContextListener* - maybe if I had a few it would have been different?

```
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
}

@WebListener
public class InitWebAppServlet implements ServletContextListener {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value in `@WebServlet` is not a class name.  It is a URL path.  When using only a single parameter like you show it is the equivalent of:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet"})
```

Your code could just as easily have been:

```
@WebServlet("/bobsyouruncle")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
}
```

That means that you'd access your servlet with the url `/bobsyouruncle` instead of `/MyServlet`.  See the [WebServlet javadocs](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) for more details.  Note that for annotations if you have only a single parameter it sets the element `value`.

The optional value of the `@WebListener` parameter is for a description of the listener (see [the WebListener javadocs](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html)).  It is, again, not a class name.  You can have as many `@WebListener` classes as you'd like though by using the annotation method instead of the `web.xml` method you cannot guarantee the order in which the servlet container runs them.